# Calling web service: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, https, ws-security

I debugged ssl handshake, by the log I suppose both server and client uses TLSv1.

Even tried setting `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");` still no success.

I'm unable to figure out the exact cause of this problem.

Can anyone please guide me on this. I'm using Java 1.7.0_65

```
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
  Issuer:  CN=SwissSign Platinum CA - G2, O=SwissSign AG, C=CH
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4eb200670c035d4f
  Valid from Wed Oct 25 14:06:00 IST 2006 until Sat Oct 25 14:06:00 IST 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=info@valicert.com, CN=http://www.valicert.com/, OU=ValiCert Class 1 Policy Validation Authority, O="ValiCert, Inc.", L=ValiCert Validation Network
  Issuer:  EMAILADDRESS=info@valicert.com, CN=http://www.valicert.com/, OU=ValiCert Class 1 Policy Validation Authority, O="ValiCert, Inc.", L=ValiCert Validation Network
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1
  Valid from Sat Jun 26 03:53:48 IST 1999 until Wed Jun 26 03:53:48 IST 2019

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=thawte Primary Root CA, OU="(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Certification Services Division, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US
  Issuer:  CN=thawte Primary Root CA, OU="(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Certification Services Division, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x344ed55720d5edec49f42fce37db2b6d
  Valid from Fri Nov 17 05:30:00 IST 2006 until Thu Jul 17 05:29:59 IST 2036

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA II, OU=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA, O=TC TrustCenter GmbH, C=DE
  Issuer:  CN=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA II, OU=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA, O=TC TrustCenter GmbH, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x2e6a000100021fd752212c115c3b
  Valid from Thu Jan 12 20:08:43 IST 2006 until Thu Jan 01 04:29:59 IST 2026

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1439961979 bytes = { 41, 125, 92, 109, 179, 38, 102, 30, 6, 241, 232, 163, 238, 108, 74, 130, 87, 194, 189, 90, 101, 223, 221, 90, 208, 170, 85, 126 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 149
0000: 01 00 00 91 03 01 56 D4   13 7B 29 7D 5C 6D B3 26  ......V...).\m.&
0010: 66 1E 06 F1 E8 A3 EE 6C   4A 82 57 C2 BD 5A 65 DF  f......lJ.W..Ze.
0020: DD 5A D0 AA 55 7E 00 00   2A C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0  .Z..U...*...../.
0030: 04 C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0   07 C0 11 00 05 C0 02 C0  ....3.2.........
0040: 0C C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0   03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13 00  ................
0050: 04 00 FF 01 00 00 3E 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......>...4.2...
0060: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0070: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0080: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
0090: 0B 00 02 01 00                                     .....
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
[Raw write]: length = 154
0000: 16 03 01 00 95 01 00 00   91 03 01 56 D4 13 7B 29  ...........V...)
0010: 7D 5C 6D B3 26 66 1E 06   F1 E8 A3 EE 6C 4A 82 57  .\m.&f......lJ.W
0020: C2 BD 5A 65 DF DD 5A D0   AA 55 7E 00 00 2A C0 09  ..Ze..Z..U...*..
0030: C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E   00 33 00 32 C0 07 C0 11  .../.....3.2....
0040: 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C C0 08   C0 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D  ................
0050: 00 16 00 13 00 04 00 FF   01 00 00 3E 00 0A 00 34  ...........>...4
0060: 00 32 00 17 00 01 00 03   00 13 00 15 00 06 00 07  .2..............
0070: 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B   00 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E  ................
0080: 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00 02   00 12 00 04 00 05 00 14  ................
0090: 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00 02   01 00                    ..........
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 46                                              .F
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, protocol_version
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
Feb 29, 2016 3:16:35 PM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
SEVERE: SAAJ0009: Message send failed
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:148)
    at com.axis.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:252)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:278)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:235)
    ... 2 more

CAUSE:

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:278)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    at com.axis.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:252)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:235)
    ... 2 more

CAUSE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    at com.axis.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:252)

CAUSE:

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:278)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    at com.axis.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:252)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:235)
    ... 2 more

CAUSE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    at com.axis.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:252)

CAUSE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:144)
    at com.axis.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:252)
```

Comment: 'I suppose both server and client uses TLSv1.' Do you also have commonly supported cipher suites? I see a lots messages like 'Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: ...'.

Comment: Sorry @blafasel what does 'Ignoring unavailable cipher suite' mean. I'm new to this concepts. And how do I get around it

Comment: SSL-Handshake performs a negotiation of the protocol, the negotiation of the cipher suite to use and afterwards the initialization of this cipher (key exchange etc.). The cipher suites mentioned in the log output use either sha or md5 as a digest algorithm. I only noticed that some modern ciphers with GCM and SHA2 are missing. If the server is public available I'd suppose to get some more information of the supported cipher suites ... you could use [ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) for example.

Comment: @blafasel the server runs in our intranet.

Comment: Then I suppose to test it with `openssl s_client -connect <server-name>:<port> -tls1 -cipher <some cipher from the list above>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by setting https.protocols property. Used @blafasel suggestion to test with `openssl s_client -connect <server-name>:<port> -tls1 -cipher <some cipher from the list above>` and found that the server was using TLSv1.2. Below is the code to set the property.

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```