# Request cannot be proceed error in Jhipster registry version 4.0.0

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I downloaded `jhipster` registry version 4.0.0, imported and run the registry successfully, when I open `localhost:8761` I am getting request cannot be proceed error, there is no error information also.

When I used command mvnw I am getting an exception in thread "main" `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.` [image: screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use http protocol instead of https.

To do this go into your project `directory > .mvn > wrapper > maven-wrapper.properties`.

You will find something like `distributionUrl=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.5.3/apache-maven-3.5.3-bin.zip`.
Change this url to using http instead of https.

Other solutions are more complex but there is no harm in trying.

[Problems connecting via HTTPS/SSL through own Java client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30760134/4801359)
[Calling web service: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35893996/4801359)
[javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47717547/4801359)

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2" as extra argument